# increase express post body limit to proxied api

Tags: node.js, express, nuxt.js

I have a seperate frontend and backend, where all requests to http://frontend.com/api are proxied to the backend. However we allow image uploads to be 10mb max, which gets limited by the 1mb internal limit of express on all request bodies.

I have the following config:

```
const express = require('express');
const consola = require('consola');
const { Nuxt, Builder } = require('nuxt');
const helmet = require('helmet');

// Express
const app = express();
const host = process.env.HOST || '127.0.0.1';
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.set('port', port);

// Import and Set Nuxt.js options
const config = require('../nuxt.config.js');

config.dev = !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production');

async function start() {
  // Init Nuxt.js
  const nuxt = new Nuxt(config);

  if (config.dev) {
    const builder = new Builder(nuxt);
    await builder.build();
  }

  // NOTE: Only in production mode
  if (!config.dev) {
    // Helmet default security + Referrer + Features
    app.use(helmet());
  }

  // Proxy /api to proper backend
  app.use('/api', proxy(process.env.API_ENDPOINT || 'http://localhost:3000'));

  // Give nuxt middleware to express
  app.use(nuxt.render);

  // Listen the server
  app.listen(port, host);
  consola.ready({
    message: `Server listening on http://${host}:${port}`,
    badge: true,
  });
}
start();
```

I have tried adding body-parser, until I found out this only works for non multipart/form type of requests. Considering that this isn't an express backend, but only used to serve SSR (with nuxt), I have no idea how to get this to work with something like multer or busboy.

Can this be done without having to setup nginx as a reverse proxy?

Comment: I've used what sounds like a similar setup to you and use multer and set my upload limits with it. I can post my code in an answer if you'd like to see it. I haven't tried it with files over 1mb so can't vouch for that but it may work. Let me know.

Comment: Would be nice to see an example, wonder if you hardcoded the endpoints or only used it as a proxy for parsing the body.

Comment: _"which gets limited by the 1mb internal limit of express on all request bodies"_. There is no such thing, though. Perhaps one of the other middleware that you're using (`helmet`, `proxy`) are responsible for imposing a limit. The stack trace of the error you're getting might provide some insight.

Comment: @robertklep You were right, I could have sworn that I read that express imposes a limit somewhere, and come to think of it, being a default that is this hard to change wouldn't be very lucrative. The only express limit I could find is for json bodies: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json. In the end "express-force-https" sets a hard limit of 1mb for all proxied requests. Changing this fixed the issue. If you could make an answer of it, I would gladly accept it :).

Comment: @user1213904 `express-force-https` doesn't set a limit either :)

Comment: :') "express-http-proxy" i meant. Thinking of one thing, writing the other...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express itself doesn't impose any limits on body size, because it doesn't process the request body at all.

However, some middleware *do* impose a limit, like `body-parser` and [`express-http-proxy`](https://github.com/villadora/express-http-proxy#limit), which is what you're using.

To increase the limit to 10MB:

```
app.use('/api', proxy(process.env.API_ENDPOINT || 'http://localhost:3000', {
  limit: '10mb'
));
```

Answer (score 0):

The way mine works is I define my api base url in a config file which I reference in an api/init.js file. This file is added to plugins in nuxt.config.js. This is that file:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import {baseURL} from '~/config'
import cookies from 'js-cookie'
import {setAuthToken, resetAuthToken} from '~/utils/auth'
import { setUser, setCart } from '../utils/auth'

axios.defaults.baseURL = baseURL

const token = cookies.get('x-access-token')
const currentUser = cookies.get('userDetails')
const currentCart = cookies.get('userCart')

if (token) {
    setAuthToken(token)
    setUser(currentUser)
    setCart(currentCart)
} else {
    resetAuthToken()
}
```

The backend runs on it's own server which I launch with `node index.js` and it is the base url that my init.js looks for. The backend index.js looks like this:

```
const mysql = require('mysql')
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const config = require('./config')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt')
const multer = require('multer')
const auth = require('./auth')
const files = require('./files')
const create = require('./create')
const get = require('./get')
const delet = require('./delet')
const blogFiles = require('./blogFiles')

const db = mysql.createConnection(config.db)
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Length, x-access-token, userDetails, userCart')
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
      res.sendStatus(200)
    }
    else {
      next()
    }
})

app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_TYPES') {
      res.status(422).json({ error: 'Only images are allowed'})
      return
  }
  if (err.code === 'LIMIT_FILE_SIZE') {
      res.status(422).json({ error: `Too Large. Max filesize is ${MAX_SIZE/1000}kb` })
      return
  }
})

app.use('/auth', auth({db, express, bcrypt, jwt, jwtToken: config.jwtToken}))
app.use('/files', files({db, express, multer}))
app.use('/blogFiles', blogFiles({db, express, multer}))
app.use('/create', create({db, express}))
app.use('/get', get({db, express}))
app.use('/delet', delet({db, express}))

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  db.query('select 1+1', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.status(500).json({type: 'error', error})
    }
    res.json({type: 'success', message: 'Test OK', results})
  })
})

app.listen(config.port)
console.log('App is running on port ' + config.port)
```

The files.js handles file uploads and as you can see index.js requires that. It is in there that I use multer to handle the upload limit and such. This is file.js

```
module.exports = ({db, express, multer }) => {
    const routes = express.Router()

    const fileFilter = function(req, file, cb) {
        const allowedTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']
        if (!allowedTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
            const error = new Error('Wrong file type')
            error.code = 'LIMIT_FILE_TYPES'
            return cb(error, false)
        }

        cb(null, true)
    }

    const MAX_SIZE = 250000

    var storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, '../frontend/assets/images')
        },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, file.originalname)
        }
      })

    const upload = multer ({
        storage: storage,
        fileFilter,
        limits: {
            fileSize: MAX_SIZE
        },

    })

    routes.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
      res.json({ file: req.file })
    })

    return routes
  }
```

As you can see I set the MAX_SIZE for my file uploads here so guess you can set any limit and as multer is handling it, it will over ride any limits set by express.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer, however my backend is in Rails unfortunately. I didn't account for the proxy which passes all requests to http://frontend/api would enforce a hard limit of 1mb. Altogether, your answer is a clear future reference.